# How to connect reactive forms with Model in order sent data to database

Tags: angular, typescript, spring-boot, jhipster

I have an application (frontend angular backend Java Spring boot with jhipster generated). And a reactive form where I am saving material for example something like a screw. But I can not seem to connect it correctly with my Model class of material I only can save one property and that is quantity. I tried to solve it with [(ngModel)] here is what I tried but it only works with quantity. Seller name and PRice Amount work fine too. What I do not understand is why one property works but not the other ones, I could not seem to find the mistake.

```
<div class="input-group input-group-sm col-12 col-md-6 mb-4">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <span class="input-group-text" id="materialName">Name</span>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Sizing example input"
                   aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm"
                   formControlName="name"
                   [(ngModel)]="materialModel.name" name="name">
          </div>
          <div class="input-group input-group-sm col-12 col-md-6 mb-4">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <span class="input-group-text" id="materialCode">Material No</span>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Sizing example input"
                   aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm"
                   formControlName="articleNumber"
                   name="articleNumber"
                   [(ngModel)]="materialModel.articleNumber">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row mb-4">
          <div class="input-group input-group-sm col-12 col-md-6 mb-4">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <span class="input-group-text" id="quantity">Quantity</span>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Sizing example input"
                   formControlName="quantity"
                   [(ngModel)]="materialModel.quantity" name="quantity"
                   aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm">
          </div>
          <div class="divider"></div>
          <div class="-pull-right">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" (click)="addSellerInput()">Add Seller</button>
          </div>
          <div class="form-row mb-4" formArrayName="buyInformation"
               *ngFor="let buyInformation of buyInformation().controls; let i = index">
            <div class="input-group input-group-sm col-12 col-md-6 mb-4" [formGroupName]="i">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text" id="sellerName">Seller Name</span>
              </div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Sizing example input"
                     aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm"
                     formControlName="seller"
                     [(ngModel)]="sellerModel.name">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group input-group-sm col-12 col-md-6 mb-4" [formGroupName]="i">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text" id="materialUnitPrice">Price</span>
              </div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Sizing example input"
                     aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm"
                     formControlName="price"
                     name="price"
                     [(ngModel)]="priceModel.amount">
            </div>
          </div>
```

This is my ts file for it:

```
materialAddForm: FormGroup;
  formData: any;
  @Input()
  materialModel: MaterialModel
  @Input()
  priceModel: PriceModel
  @Input()
  sellerModel: SellerModel

  constructor(
    private materialService: MaterialService,
    private priceService: PriceService,
    private sellerService: SellerService,
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) {
    this.materialModel = new MaterialModel()
    this.priceModel = new PriceModel()
    this.sellerModel = new SellerModel()

  }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.materialAddForm = this.fb.group({
      name: new FormControl(''),
      articleNumber: new FormControl(''),
      materialType: new FormControl(''),
      quantity: new FormControl(''),
      buyInformation: this.fb.array([])
    })
  }


  buyInformation(): FormArray {
    return this.materialAddForm.get("buyInformation") as FormArray
  }

  saveMaterial() {
    this.sellerService.addSeller(this.sellerModel).subscribe(console.log);
    this.priceService.addPrice(this.priceModel).subscribe(console.log);
    this.materialService.addMaterial(this.materialModel).subscribe(console.log);
    this.materialAddForm.reset()
    this.buyInformation().clear()


    console.log(this.materialModel)

  }

  newBuyForm() {
    return this.fb.group(({
      seller: new FormControl(''),
      price: new FormControl(''),
    }));
  }

  addSellerInput() {
    this.buyInformation().push(this.newBuyForm())

  }
```

And my model of Material:

```
export class MaterialModel{
  constructor(
    public id?: number,
    public name?: string,
    public articleNumber?: number,
    public quantity?: number,
    public price?: number,
    public imageURL?: string,
    public materialType?: string
     ) {}


}
```

Only quantity works so far in the material.

Answer (score 1):

Really there are some mistakes in your code

1.-use interface vs class

If your use class only to defined properties it's better use interfaces.

```
export interface MaterialModel{
    public id?: number;
    public name?: string;
    public articleNumber?: number;
    public quantity?: number;
    public price?: number;
    public imageURL?: string;
    public materialType?: string;
}
```

2.-There're two ways to create a FormGroup, using the constructor (each property of the formGroup is a new FormControl or a new FormGroup or a new FormArray)

```
this.form=new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl(''),
      articleNumber: new FormControl(''),
      materialType: new FormControl(''),
      ...
      buyInformation: new FormArray([])
})
```

**or** using FormBuilder (see that in this case **don't** use new FormControl)

```
this.form=this.fb.group({
      name: [''],
      articleNumber: [''],
      materialType: [''],
      ...
      buyInformation: this.fb.array([])
})
```

3.-When you use httpClient to make a post, you pass as argument of "data" a JSON object, you can use directly this.form.value (or create a object "ad hoc" with the value of the form.value)

```
//if the properties of the form is the same you need, you can do
    this.sellerService.addSeller(this.materialAddForm.value)
          .subscribe((res:any)=>{console.log(res)});

//or 
    this.sellerService.addSeller({
           materialName:this.materialAddForm.value.name
           material_code:this.materialAddForm.value.articleNumber
           ...
          })
          .subscribe((res:any)=>{console.log(res)});
```

4.- NOT mixe [(ngModel)] and formControlName in the same tag.

5.- generally (but really it's optional) usially we use a "getter" to get the formArray

```
   get buyInformation(): FormArray {
    return this.materialAddForm.get("buyInformation") as FormArray
  }
```

To use as ,e.g.

```
<!--see that we remove the ()-->
<div *ngFor="let buyInformation of buyInformation.controls;.." >
```

6.- get out the "formArrayName" of the loop, well, work, but it's a few cofussed

```
<div formArrayName="buyInformation">
    <div *ngFor="let buyInformation of buyInformation.controls;let i=index"
        [formGroupName]="i">
         <input formControlName="seller">
    </div>
</div>
```

7.- if you use a `@Input` to pass data, use this input to create the form. For this, I like has a function that return a FormGroup

```
getFormGroup(data:any=null)
{
   data=data || {} as MaterialModel
   return new FormControl({
      name: new FormControl(''),
      articleNumber: new FormControl(''),
      materialType: new FormControl(''),
      quantity: new FormControl(''),
      buyInformation: data.byInfomation?new FormArray(data.buyInformation.map(x=>this.newBuyForm(x)):
         new FormArray([])
    })
}
//and 
newBuyForm(data:any=null)
{
   data=data || { seller:'',price:0}
   return new FormGroup(({
      seller: new FormControl(data.seller),
      price: new FormControl(data.price),
    }));
}
```

So, in input, see that if you don't use materialModel anymore, you can only use the FromGroup

```
@Input() set materialModel(value){
    this.materialAddForm=this.getFormGroup(value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. The problem was that the names of the fields and the names of my model were different.

For example: In my model it was called name but in my backend materialName. After naming them the same way it worked. And could delete ngModel:

and had to do this in order bind my model and form:

```
saveMaterialForm(material: MaterialModel){
    material.materialName = this.materialAddForm.get(['name']).value;
    material.material_code = this.materialAddForm.get(['articleNumber']).value;
    material.material_type = this.materialAddForm.get(['materialType']).value;
    material.quantity = this.materialAddForm.get(['quantity']).value;
    //material.name = this.materialAddForm.get(['name']).value;

  }
```